# $digest error with no model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the following error in Angularjs:

```
"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}; oldVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}; oldVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}; oldVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}; oldVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}; oldVal: {\"x\":0,\"y\":0}"]]
```

**The `newVal` and `oldVal` logs are all the same.** According to [How to Troubleshoot Angular "10 $digest() iterations reached" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error), the error should be thrown when the value changes.

This is my **app code**:

```
$scope.getCommentLocation = function(comment) {
        console.log("TEST");
        if (comment == undefined) { // This is all that gets returned every time
            return {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            };
        }
        $range = getRangeObjectForComment(comment);
        position = $range.offset();
        window_position_y = position.top - $('#main-text_ifr').contents().find('body').scrollTop() + frameposition.top + $range.height() / 2;
        window_position_x = position.left + frameposition.left + $range.width() / 2;
        return {
            x: window_position_x,
            y: window_position_y
        };
    };
```

This is the **jade code** (Jade is an html template language):

```
location="getCommentLocation(commentEditor.activeComment)"
```

Comment: The objects returned are equal, but not identical.

Comment: @Blackhole Oh, because they're different objects? How do I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will always create a new object and returns it.

```
          return {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            };
```

Use a referrence variable kind of $scope.origin which will be only defined once outiside the `$scope.getCommentLocation`.
`$scope.origin ={x:0, y:0};//never recreate this any where just use the origin referrence`

and use `return $scope.origin`