# Debugging $rootScope:infdig

Tags: angularjs

This is a common problem:

> 5 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! 
>     Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

The documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) explains what NOT to do to avoid the situation.

However, once in a while, you end up in the situation anyway. And for a project larger than a toy app, finding the cause of the infinite digest loop can be really hard.

I'm looking for debugging hints on how I can find out where the code is located which causes the loop.

Answer (score 11):

question was already answered here - [How to Troubleshoot Angular "10 $digest() iterations reached" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17116114/274500)

as a resume of two best answers:

1. **remove all suspicious HTML** - basically remove all your html from the template, and check if there are no warnings (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129274/274500)
2. usually it happens when **function returns an new object** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17116322/274500)

plus

you can always put **conditional breakpoint** here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c3220325a0a95484724a03bedca24e1bbf05dc80/src/ng/rootScope.js#L815 to check the exception stacktrace.

Comment: In my case the problem was that there was no infinite loop at all, as i made sure to always return the same object reference. I have detailed how to debug that in [an answer on the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38981431/546730). This case is quite rare though...

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple reasons to it. One of the common reason I've faced is due to a filter in the `ng-repeat` which returns a new array to work on the `ng-repeat`.

So check your `ng-repeat` expressions which have associated filters which is modifying the array.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was happening in a method changing the url:

```
  self.setURL = function(item) {
    var mainUrl = window.location.origin + '#/' + self.baseUrl;
    if (item) {
      mainUrl += item.testId;
    }
    $location.$$absUrl = mainUrl;
  };
```

this was causing the `$rootScope:infdig` error

So when debugging this check whatever is changing your ur, location, hrefs in your current controller/directive

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was happening in a method changing the url:

```
> self.setURL = function(item) {
>    
> 
>//Ajax call followed by promise function
>      servicejsfile.somefunctiom(transferObj).then(responce){
>        

> var somethingTrue=responce.featureAvailable;
>if (somethingTrue) {
> dothis();
>}else
> $window.location = newlocation;
> };
```

This change the last portion of URL of my application.
this was causing the $rootScope:infdig error

So when debugging this, I commented out this portion, and error was not repeated along with requirement of application also changed.

I am not able to fix this so we requirement remains same and I can change the location.

This issue is taking place from some a **Ajax call inside a funtion of a controller, and only in IE** For FF , chrome and safari it is behaving perfect as JavaScript engine is faster for these browsers.