# Angular Strap Tooltip Container Set to Directive Element

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-strap, angularjs-digest

I have created a directive that, given the required data, will produce an input field with validation rules, validation messages and an angular-strap Tooltip.

I would like the tooltip to align with the form row so that, even when validation errors hide and show, the tooltip always aligns with the input.

To achieve this I have set the container of the tooltip to the element of the directive.

```
        scope.elementData.Tooltip = {
            "title": scope.elementData['Help Text'],
            "container": element // <<<<<<<<< 
        }
```

However - I get the following error:

```
 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Oddly the tooltip is now placed inside the container, fixing the issue, but there are nasty console errors as above.

See a working example here: http://plnkr.co/bdH4xcUKmWTocVlEWLtI?p=preview.

If anyone could help in figuring out the cause of the $digest error I would be most grateful. I have found this [How to Troubleshoot Angular "10 $digest() iterations reached" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error) but I can't quite see how this relates to the issues described there. Again any help would be much appreciated.