# Error 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [] . where i using ui router

Tags: angularjs

I want to resolve my login page before getting login page. my intent to check user is already logged in or not.
My code is blow.
My Function which content business logic :
[image]

ui route and state :

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error