# How to solve angular '$digest() iterations reached. Aborting!' error

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have this code in my HTML:

```
                <uib-pagination
                   previous-text="{{previousText}}" 
                   next-text="{{nextText}}"
                </uib-pagination>
```

My angular translate is being $watch:

```
        $translate(['PREVIOUS', 'NEXT']).then(function (translations) {
            $scope.previousText = translations.PREVIOUS;
            $scope.nextText = translations.NEXT;
        });
```

but then I get this error:

[image]

I'll try to solve it with this tutorial :

1. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig
2. [How to Troubleshoot Angular "10 $digest() iterations reached" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error)

but I'm still getting same errors. I try to troubleshoot by removing some code and this is my new code but I'm still getting same errors.

```
        $scope.$watch(function()
        {
            $translate().then(function () {

            });
        }, true);
```

I am clueless right now. How can I solve this problem? by the way, the pagination did managed to translated but I've seen this error in my console and it's not neat. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check `$scope.$$phase()`?

Comment: $watch callback is called every cycle. And `$translate().then` triggers another digest (that's how $q promises work). This is infinite digest. `$translate()` calls can be limited to language changes or whatever. Why is `$translate` and not `translate` filter used, btw?

Comment: Quite often infdig means infdig = after running watches something in scope changes, so watches run again and something changes again and so on... i.e. watching function that return no value makes no sence to me

Comment: @estus I did use `translate` but unfortunately for pagination it failed to translate dynamically. That's why I had to use `$translate`

Comment: It should work with filter if you're doing everything right, I would suggest to do this. It is clear why you're doing this in $scope.$watch the way you do, especially because it is expected that it will cause infinite digest.