# AngularFire '10 $digest() iterations reached' error when retrieving data from multiple nodes

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

My web application uses Firebase JS and AngularJS to display a list of event registrations and the users who have registered for each event. The events and the users' data are in different database nodes.

Database:

```
"event_registrations" : {
    "$event_id" : {
        "$user_id" : {
           "registration_date" : "..." 
           "total_amount" : "...",
        }
    }
},

"users" : {
    "$user_id" : {
      "events" : {
        "event_id" : 1
      },
      "profile" : {
        "email" : "..."
        "name" : "...",
        // ...
      }
    },
}
```

Angular:

```
function MyController($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    // Retrieve event data
    $scope.events = scope.firebaseRef.child('event_registrations');

    // Retrieve user_data
    $scope.getUserData = function(userID) {
        var ref = $firebaseObject(scope.firebaseRef
           .child('users')
           .child(userID)
           .child('profile'));

        ref.$ref().once("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
            var data = dataSnapshot.val();
            $scope.user_data = data;
        });
    };
 }
```

Web page:

```
 <div ng-repeat="event in event_registrations">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="(user_id, user_data) in event">
                {{getUserData(user_id)}}

                <td>{{user_data.email}}</td>
                <td>{{user_data.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that when `getUserData()` is called from the web page, a `10 $digest() iterations reached` error is produced and the data on the web page stops updating in realtime when it is updated in the Firebase DB.

How can this be solved? I have looked at Firebase-Util but am unsure how to specifically utilize it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

From [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write),

To read data at a path and listen for changes, use the `on()` or `once()` methods of `firebase.database.Reference` to observe events.

For updating in real time, you should be using `on()` method. This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.

In your case,

```
ref.$ref().on("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
        var data = dataSnapshot.val();
        $scope.user_data = data;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but changing it to on() still produces the '10 $digest() iterations reached' error.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129274/7004388) might help you. Please refer all the answers which were posted in the provided link. @user2181948

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by simply returning the Firebase database reference in `getUserData()`:

```
 $scope.getUserData = function(userID) {
    var ref = $firebaseObject(scope.firebaseRef
        .child('users')
        .child(userID)
        .child('profile'));

    return ref;
};
```

Then calling `getUserData()` in `ng-init` of the ng-repeat` element

```
<tr ng-repeat="(user_id, user_data) in event" ng-init="user_data=getUserData(user_id)>
      <td>{{user_data.email}}</td>
      <td>{{user_data.name}}</td>
</tr>
```